# ASP .NET MVC 4, datatables submit and concurrent form submits

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery, datatables

So, what I'm trying to do here is rather simple, in my ASP .NET MVC4 application, I've a table from which the user can pick different invoices to get a generated PDF in return (A pdf of all the invoices to be clear). I'm using datatables to decorate the table.

I realized however that the pagination destroy DOM objects, so before sending the form I've to load all the row from the table into a decoy:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("getPDF", "Invoice", FormMethod.Post, new { id="PostForm" }))
{
    <table style="display:none;">        
    </table>
}

<table id="invoiceTable">
    <thead>
        --Snip of headers--
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And when the form is submitted I simply use this little js/jquery

```
$('#PostForm').submit(function () {
    $('table', this).append(oTable.fnGetNodes());
    return true;
});
```

And it works neatly, in the controller I receive the complete table and I generate my little PDF.

However this pose a problem, because after the submit I have a invisible table full of useless data I need to clean. I can't turn the form into a Ajax form since I'm trying to download a file. What I wanted to do however is run an Ajax query in parallel and synchronize the 2 answers server side, probably by using a Session object.

**So here goes the first question, is this the proper approach for that problem ?**

Not knowing the answer to that question I went ahead and tried to run a Ajax query in parallel :

```
$('#PostForm').submit(function () {
    $('table', this).append(oTable.fnGetNodes());

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Invoice/getPDFAjaxSync",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('hello');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    return true;
});
```

And this doesn't work, the ajax query on it's own works, but when I try to run it inside the submit of the PostForm form it always fail with no errors message whatsoever, it reaches the server method, a breakpoint confirm that, but it fails client side even if the server is still paused by the breakpoint.
So here goes the second question :

**Is it possible to run 2 submits at the same time, one normal submit and an Ajax one ? And if yes how do I do that ?**

**Edit:** 
So I found an other approach to my problem, I separated the server function getPDF into 2 function, one that ready the data, the other that generate the PDF :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult readyPDF(IEnumerable<InvoiceListableViewModel> invoiceViewModels)
{
    SysParam l_sp = db.SysParams.Single(sp => sp.paramId == 1);

    int[] l_invoiceId = invoiceViewModels
                        .Where(ivm => ivm.Pick)
                        .Select(ivm => ivm.InvoiceId)
                        .ToArray();

    List<PDFTemplateViewModel> l_inv = /*load data*/
                                 .ToList();
    Session.Add("InvoicesToPrint", l_inv);
    return new JsonResult();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult getPDF()
{
    List<PDFTemplateViewModel> l_inv = new List<PDFTemplateViewModel>();

    if (Session["InvoicesToPrint"] != null && Session["InvoicesToPrint"] is List<PDFTemplateViewModel>)
        l_inv = (List<PDFTemplateViewModel>)Session["InvoicesToPrint"];

    return new ViewAsPdf("DisplayTemplates/PDFTemplates/PDFReportMain", l_inv)
        {
            FileName = "Invoices.pdf",
        };;
}
```

I Ajaxified the form on the page, and once the callback is done I download the data from an iframe

```
$('#PostForm').submit(function () {
    $('#hiddenTable', this).append(oTable.fnGetNodes());

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            oTable.fnDraw();
            $('#PdfLoader').attr('src', '@Url.Action("getPDF")');
        },
    });

    return false;
});
```

And bam it works, my only problem now is knowing when the file is ready to be downloaded, with the load event of the iframe, surprisingly no problem with onreadystatechange but onload still resists me

Comment: This is actually a very interesting and good question. I'm assuming you are using clientside pagination? To be honest I don't find that approach too hacky given the (understandable) limitations of ajax.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, forgot to mention that the pagination is indeed done client side. I found a solution to my problem however, using an iframe, I'm still facing some issues with the load event, but I think it's heading the right direction. I'll will edit my question to add my new approach, but I'll leave the question open if others are interested